# widget: Setting to control "y/n" confirmation with system popup versus minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, mouse, confirmation

On OSX, using the following variable/keymap and code snippet, a mouse click on the "SUBMIT" button will generate a system popup confirmation message, whereas an enter key on the "SUBMIT" button will generate a minibuffer confirmation message.  Is there setting to control whether the confirmation is requested in the minibuffer versus a system popup?

**VARIABLE**:   `my-widget-keymap`

```lisp
(defvar my-widget-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [down-mouse-2] 'widget-button-click)
    (define-key map [down-mouse-1] 'widget-button-click)
    (define-key map "\r" 'widget-button-press)
    map)
  "Keymap containing useful binding for buffers containing widgets.")
```

**CODE SNIPPET**:

```
(let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*TEST*")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (erase-buffer)
    (widget-create 'push-button
               :tag "SUBMIT"
               :format "%[%v%]"
               :keymap my-widget-keymap
               :notify `(lambda (_wid &rest _ignore)
                          (when (y-or-n-p "proceed?")
                            (message "Hello-World!")))))
  (display-buffer buffer t))
```

Comment: The doc string for `y-or-no-p` says: `Under a windowing system a dialog box will be used if ‘last-nonmenu-event’
is nil and ‘use-dialog-box’ is non-nil.` So I think you can get the question in the minibuffer even if you click. I'm not sure whether you can get a pop-up with a RET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NickD suggested in a comment, try customizing or binding variable `use-dialog-box` to `nil`, to use the keyboard (minibuffer input) to confirm y/n even when you click the push button with the mouse.

(Using keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`RET`) on the button will always use the minibuffer for (keyboard) confirmation.)

Comment: @NickD: Oops. Thx; typo corrected.